# storing pointers of methods of one class into another class

Tags: c++, boost

I have class `A` which has methods `void fun(int, int)` and `void fun1(int, int)`. These are non-static methods.

```
struct A {
    void fun(int,int){}
    void fun1(int,int){}
};
```

Now inside class `B` I want to store pointer to one of the method.

Which means `object1` of `B` will have pointer to `fun` and `object2` of `B` will have pointer to `fun1`.

Now my `set_handler()` and pointer to handler has to be generic.

One way is to use function pointers. 
So that that I can use `void(A::*pointer)(int,int)` which can store address of `fun` or `fun1`.

```
struct B {
    typedef void(A::*pointer)(int,int);
    pointer f;

    void set_handler(pointer p) { f = p; }
};

int main() {
    {
        B object1;
        object2.set_handler(&A::fun);
    }
    {
        B object2;
        object2.set_handler(&A::fun1);
    }
}
```

I was looking into `boost::bind()` but it needs specific name. How do I use boost here?

Comment: If storing method pointers will work, why use boost?

Comment: I edited your question the way you probably should have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I malled your question into running code that actually does something with the pointer - so we know when the goal has been achieved:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a914f8d1561eb055)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void fun(int  a, int b) { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl; }
    void fun1(int a, int b) { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl; }
};

struct B {
    typedef void (A::*pointer)(int, int);
    pointer f;

    void set_handler(pointer p) { f = p; }

    void run(A& instance) {
        (instance.*f)(42, 42);
    }
};

int main() {
    B object1;
    B object2;
    object1.set_handler(&A::fun);
    object2.set_handler(&A::fun1);

    A a;
    object1.run(a);
    object2.run(a);
}
```

Prints

```
fun(42,42)
fun1(42,42)
```

### Using `boost::function` or `std::function`

You have to allow for the instance argument (the implicit `this` parameter):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b07f336b0ac4b3b3)</kbd>**

```
struct B {
    using function = std::function<void(A&, int, int)>;
    function f;

    void set_handler(function p) { f = p; }

    void run(A& instance) {
        f(instance, 42, 42);
    }
};
```

Which prints the same output. Of course you can use `boost::function` and `boost::bind` just the same

### What about bind?

Bind comes in when you want to **adapt** the function signatures. So, e.g. you want to bind to any instance of `A&` without actually passing it into `run()`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6487246045f87e73)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    std::string name;
    void fun(int  a, int b) { std::cout << "name:" << name << " " << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl; }
    void fun1(int a, int b) { std::cout << "name:" << name << " " << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl; }
};

struct B {
    using function = std::function<void(int, int)>;
    function f;

    void set_handler(function p) { f = p; }

    void run() {
        f(42, 42);
    }
};

int main() {
    B object1;
    B object2;
    A a1 {"black"};
    A a2 {"white"};

    {
        using namespace std::placeholders;
        object1.set_handler(std::bind(&A::fun, &a1, _1, _2));
        object2.set_handler(std::bind(&A::fun1, &a2, _1, _2));
    }

    object1.run();
    object2.run();
}
```

Which prints:

```
name:black fun(42,42)
name:white fun1(42,42)
```

### More Goodness

From c++ you can do without bind and its pesky placeholders (there are other caveats, like bind storing all arguments by value). Instead, you may use lambdas:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc0a06027a179d74)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    std::string name;
    void fun(int  a, int b) { std::cout << "name:" << name << " " << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl; }
    void fun1(int a, int b) { std::cout << "name:" << name << " " << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl; }
};

struct B {
    using function = std::function<void(int, int)>;
    function f;

    void set_handler(function p) { f = p; }

    void run() {
        f(42, 42);
    }
};

int main() {
    B object1;
    B object2;

    object1.set_handler([](int a, int b) {
            A local_instance {"local"};
            local_instance.fun(a*2, b*3); // can even do extra logic here
        });

    A main_instance {"main"};
    object2.set_handler([&main_instance](int a, int b) {
            main_instance.fun1(a, b); // can even do extra logic here
        });

    object1.run();
    object2.run();
}
```

Prints

```
name:local fun(84,126)
name:main fun1(42,42)
```

Comment: great.! Thanks for so detailed answer. Wish could accept it multiple times :)